# Can initramfs mount multiple partitions?

Tags: systemd, luks, initramfs

We're using `dm-crypt` to encrypt a data disk and would like to use [Mandos](https://wiki.recompile.se/wiki/Mandos) to facilitate unattended boot.  Unfortunately, I'm to understand that:

- Mandos depends on the `keyscript` feautre of crypttab,
- [systemd's implementation of crypttab lacks support for keyscript](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1451032/), and
- Even if it happened to work on our current version (14.04 with `upstart`), Ubuntu will soon use `systemd` by default and I'd rather not design a ticking timebomb into our infrastructure

If the system drive is encrypted (not in our case), the normal strategy is to use `initramfs` (which supports `keyscript`), but this reportedly only mounts the system drive by default (see comment #6, link above).

Is it possible to mount additional disks using initramfs, while `keyscript` (and thus Mandos) is still available?  Any hints or gotchas since this will be my first time trying to use initramfs?  Is there some better strategy, for example a blog post mentions using `cryptdisks_start` post-boot[1]?

[1] blog.night-shade.org.uk/2015/04/etccrypttab-systemd-and-passwords/ (not enough reputation for a second, real link)

Comment: systemd mounts encrypted partitions on fedora and I see no reason it will not work in Ubuntu, perhaps without keyscript, I am not sure. Personally I would suggest you install a more modern version of Ubuntu rather then start with 14.04 and upgrade to systemd.

Comment: See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup-generator.html and https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64693/how-do-i-configure-systemd-to-activate-an-encrypted-swap-file

Comment: @bodhi, I'm not clear how crypttab documents are helping me since (1) I linked to the bug "keyscript option in crypttab not implemented" affecting "systemd[ubuntu]" and (2) Mandos (apparently) uses `keyscript` to load the password from the remote server and provide it to crypttab.  The combination seems to be a fatal gap in the normal operation.

Comment: I am not sure how Ubuntu will fix the bug. IMHO your question is off topic as you are asking about a potential problem and a bug report. Do you have an actual problem ? I assume Ubuntu is going to either patch keyscript or go with the freedesktop standard, you can ask on the mailing list.

Comment: I'm trying to _work around_ that specific bug so I figured a community affected by the bug would be most likely to have a workaround.  My idea was to work around the issue using `initramfs`.  `initramfs` may technically be off topic (I gather it's not Ubuntu-specific), but it's just one proposal (a tool commonly used in Ubuntu) and someone in the Ubuntu world might have another/better.

Comment: Here is how I write an intramfs . Works with lvm and luks . There is nothing in the intramfs that is specific to gnetoo. http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/initramfs/